# How to hide a builtin module name when importing or using it in other module

Tags: python, unit-testing

I use python unittest framework to do the integration test. To eliminate the confusion, I would like to inherit TestCase class in a way as "integrationtest.TestCase" instead of "unittest.TestCase".

Furthermore it will be even nicer if I can also do "import integrationtest" rather than "import unittest", similar for "unittest.main()", better to call it with "integrationtest.main()"

I'm new to python and unittest framework. Could you kindly give some advices?

Answer (score 0):

I don't agree that there is any need to do what you are trying to do, anyway you can easily achieve what you want. Define a python module called `integrationtest.py` with the following contents:

```
from unittest import *
from unittest import mock   # python3
```

Make sure the module is in a place where it can be imported by your integration tests. Now you can access all `unittest` facilities by importing this module.

*Note:* the single `*`-import is not enough to import submodules, hence the need for the `from unittest import mock` line.

This practice is not common in Python, and as such I'd discourage it.

Comment: Does this solution work for python 2.7? I'm currently working with this version. And is it a good practice to inherited all used classes in unit test? In addition, I also would like to extend something for the integrationtest, which is another reason why I would like to do it in this way.

Comment: @Potatototototo Yes, however you may need to remove the `mock` part since it is not available in python2.7 by default (but consider installing `unittest2` instead of using the stdlib one...). You are free to do whatever you want in `integrationtest`.